# bash: g++: command not found in sublime text editor on mac

Tags: c++

When I run the program so I get following text on my editor I set path but I did not get it whats I am doing wrong please provide the exact solution.

[image]

Comment: you probably need to install g++.
if you're on Ubuntu, this should work
    `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Answer (score 0):

The Sublime Text editor didn't find any G++ compiler in your machine.

You can install G++ compiler with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc-c++
```